# Cobol triggering a URL by passing query string paramters

Tags: cobol

Looking to to setup a COBOL batch job on mainframe which would be triggered weekly . Would it be possible to trigger a URL by passing query string parameters from COBOL ?

Comment: Triggering a Cobol Job weekly - Yes use a scheduling system (OPC, CA-Scheduler etc, All mainframe systems will have one, ask around). URL query ???, would think scheduling package would be a better option.

Comment: Talk to the Mainframe Tecnical/Production Control staff and find out how they want you to do what you actually want. They will know what products are available, and the standards for doing it at that site. They will not be keen on cobbled-together ideas from the internet.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would question the architecture. There are plenty of existing ways to trigger outbound events from the mainframe. All file transfer products are capable of it, just something off the top of my head. Another simple way would be to just include a job step invoking ftp and pushing a file into a directory somewhere on some server - a gazillion ways to watch it, pick it up and trigger anything you want. The idea I am trying to express is Cobol is not the best vehicle for this kind of things, do it on the JCL level as a separate job step and use the simplest way acceptable at your organization to push a file out of the mainframe. Watch for it, and then you are totally free to do anything.
2. If you insist on doing it right there, while your Cobol program is running, then I'd suggest having a Java program doing it and calling it from Cobol (assuming you are on z/OS - I doubt it's feasible on VSE but I'm out of my depth there.) Still way more complex than option 1, or even having a Java program running as a separate job step, but way simpler than trying to do an HTTP request from Cobol.